# response of sending email in android

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to send an email using default method

```
eml.setType("message/rfc822");
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(eml, "Choose an Email client :"), RESULT_EMAIL_SEND);
```

Now i am using `startActivityForResult`. I have found out that it actually never send any response back so it gets its default value as Activity_Cancel.

Now my problem is,

I want to do following

> Main Page -> Activity -> Email > Success -> Main page Main Page ->
>   Activity -> Email > Failed (if no internet or any other probelm) ->
>   Back to activity

How can i do that?
Best REGARDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i do that?

Generally speaking, you can't, unless you send the email yourself (e.g., via the JavaMail JAR).

Comment: @user966227: What CommonsWare is effectively saying is that a 3rd-party email client isn't going to be guaranteed to return any meaningful result (and most probably wont). If you write your own email `Activity` and take out the 'chooser' part then you'll have full control.

Comment: @MisterSquonk by defining my own mail activity, i have to give account name and password. I don't want the users to write down their emails and their passwords in my app

Comment: @user966227: Then you cannot achieve what you "want to do". Redesign your application such that you do not care what happens when you send the email.